# Не определился SSD диск?

Tags: ssd, diskpart

На первом SSD стоит Win 10, подключил второй(на нём win7), и он неопределился, 
нельзя разметить место и отфарматировать его, встречались с такой проблемой ? На срине ДИСК 0 это тот новый SSD который нельзя разметить. В диспетчере зада он отображается, может проблема  в том что на нём стоит Winda ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: отформатируйте его ...

Comment: Как форматировать , если он не определяется ?

Comment: напишите в google или в yandex слово diskpart и чётко следуйте инструкциям

Comment: неполучилось форматнусь, вот скрин ошибки http://prntscr.com/ottx2f

Comment: диск 0 16 kb разумеется - вы что то не так сделали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В сервисном центре ответили что он вышел из строя